# Accessing the creator account or using superadmin is the only way to gather data of courses in Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-classroom, google-workspace

Due to the events of the recent COVID-19 pandemic, my school company implemented a Google Classroom infrastructure and i need to gather all the data about access and usage of the platform in order to create reports to the scholar community.

Each unit (individual school) has an account under my domain that created several hundreds of individual courses. The number of units is over 100.

I wrote some code to do the tricks but i need clearence to acess the info of all the courses in the domain.

Is there any other way to access the info of the courses other than using the creator account or superadmin? Like creating a middle clearence account of GSuite that can pull all this data. Superadmin is very sensible.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Kind of info i'm trying to access

```
Classroom.Courses.Announcements.list(id).announcements;
Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(id).courseWork;
Classroom.Courses.Students.list(id).students;
```

Basically everything i can see about students commitment.

Comment: I am not aware of another way, but please specify which kind of data you are talking about.

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Classroom.Courses.Announcements.list

[Course teachers and domain administrators may view all announcements](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list).

### Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list

[Course teachers and domain administrators may view all course work.](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list).

### Classroom.Courses.Students.list

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list) does not provide any respective information, but the access conditions are the same.

### To conclude

Not only admins and course creators have full access to the requested methods, but also all other teachers added as such to a course.

Thus, you can add any domain user as a teacher to all courses, if this makes your work easier.

Also students have limited access to course information, however only to published items.

Comment: Thanks! That teacher trick is good. Didn't know. Thing is you can't be allocated in more than 2000 courses (yes, ther are over 2000 courses). Anyway, the guys at the IT found a solution to iterate throught the different creators account and get the info.